# Dual boot problem (Windows11 & Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, grub2, windows

I've installed Windows 11 and then Ubuntu 20.04 on my PC.

But when I turn on my PC automatically boots Windows 11 and does not ask me which OS you want to boot.

I've checked similar questions in Ask Ubuntu but didn't solved my problem.

My PC:

Disk: 2TB SSD & 1TB HDD (Windows 11 & Ubuntu are installed in the SSD)

Motherboard: MSI B450M PRO-VDH MAX

Comment: Didn't you stumbled upon similar question where the first recommendation is to check UEFI seetings > Boot and confirm "Ubuntu" (Grub) has the first priority and if not change it accordingly? There are thousands of those already...

Comment: @ChanganAuto I've changed boot mode from UEFI & Legacy to UEFI only and reinstalled Ubuntu, same problem.

Comment: UEFI mode and that one only is indeed what you want. Now, what about checking the boot order?

Comment: @ChanganAuto there is just Windows boot manager and nothing about Linux, Ubuntu or Grub

Comment: But it should be. Possible causes: Having the Windows partitions "hijacked" by the Windows' Fast Startup feature. Disabling it is a must for dual-booting. It could have preventing the installer from accessing the EFI partition and install Grub. It should be fixable without reinstalling Ubuntu. So 1. Disable Fast Startup in Windows and shutdown Wiondows. 2. Use Boot Repair (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), 2nd option - install in the same USB live session you used before. You may want to add the summary to the question and/or try applying the recommended repair (it may not work).